# How do you inherit a single function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I know how you can extend a full object with the use if it's prototype. But is it also possible to extend a single function?

```
var a = function(){}
a.prototype.test = function( p ){
    return p
}

var b = function(){};
b.prototype.test = Object.create(a.prototype.test);

var c = new a();
var d = new b();
console.log(typeof a.test, typeof b.test, typeof c.test, typeof d.test)

console.log( c.test("Unicorn") );
console.log( d.test("Unicorn") );
```

This results in

> > undefined, undefined, function(), undefined
>
> > "Unicorn"
>
> > TypeError: d.test is not a function

Comment: just directly pass the reference `b.prototype.test = a.prototype.test;` unless context is needed

Comment: You don't inherit a function.  You can call another function from within your function in order to use the behavior of another function.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not "inheriting" per se, the way to do this is create a b.test function that runs a.test;

```
b.prototype.test = function () {
    return a.prototype.test.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: What will happen if test is an object? It will break the code.

Comment: @abs Yes, this will not work for an object, there are other ways to do that, but in both the question title and body, the asker is asking how to inherit a single _function_.

Comment: got it upvote agian. But still believe it should be generic.

Answer (score 1):

we can create a dummy constructor `x` and extend its prototype with test.

```
var a = function(){}
a.prototype.test = function( p ){
    return p
}

var b = function(){};
var x = function(){};
x.prototype.test = a.prototype.test
b.prototype = new x();

var c = new a();
var d = new b();
console.log(typeof a.test, typeof b.test, typeof c.test, typeof d.test)

console.log( c.test("Unicorn") );
console.log( d.test("Unicorn") );
```

I think the simpler way is `b.prototype.test = a.prototype.test`.

Answer (score 1):

How about simply assigning that function?

```
b.prototype.test = a.prototype.test;
```